# Error: Cannot find backlight controller for radeon acpi graphics card

Tags: graphics, radeon, acpi

I get the following message every time I reboot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

drm: radeon_acpi_init  Error:  Cannot find a backlight controller

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Many thanks for your attention!

Answer (score -1):

With bootscreen check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162087#162087)
so you should change the "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" using load screen;

or if you do not have several boot options:
 after loading press Alt+CTRL+F1 -> login as user or admin -> follow Coldfish answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)

this should help

PS : as the result i can now login successfully, but i see some strange popup that says that something ith monitor connection(on my laptop)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.